# FaceTime api for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, facetime

Is there any new API available with IOS 5 to use FaceTime with our application ?

As till iOS 4 the API's were not available and I didn't find any api till so , is there any way to use it EXCEPT NSUrl method.

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not, you can only start facetime by it URL sheme: `facetime:`

If you go to the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html) you can search there for facetime. you will see no API results for facetime.